# Sort table from observable in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm doing an app in Angular 6, where I'm getting data from JSON API to table. I have to sort this data's after click on header. 
I don't know, how should I do it. I am a beginner at Angular, I am asking for your understanding

My .ts code

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly ROOT_URL = '...';
  datas: Observable<Data[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  sortTable(parm) {
    this.datas.subscribe(item => item.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return a[parm] - b[parm];
    }));
  }

  getDatas() {
    this.datas = this.http.get<Data[]>(this.ROOT_URL);
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDatas();


  }

}
```

Interface

```
export interface Data {
  long: string;
  perc: number;
  price: number;
}
```

And HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" (click)="sortTable(long)">Nazwa</th>
        <th scope="col">Cena</th>
        <th scope="col">Zmiana(24h)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let data of datas | async" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ data.long }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.price }} $</td>
        <td>{{ data.perc }} %</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Just to let you know, I've edited your post to remove the `angularjs` tag, as that only applies to angular v1, not the newer (v2+) versions you're using

Comment: If you are using something like material to style your application, stuff like that is built in. Running example here (https://mypets.glitch.me/) Source Code here (https://github.com/ng-chicago/MyPets)

Comment: There's also the [material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) component

Comment: @Mathias I can't use other materials like MatSort or MatPaginator

Comment: bummer - you have to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

You can remove async pipe, and subscribe to data with subscription function. So use sort function of Array.

```
...
datas: Array<Data>;
...
sortTable(parm) {
    // you can use one of this solutions, but I recomend localeCompare
    // this.datas.sort((a, b)=>a[parm] > b[parm]);
    this.datas.sort((a, b)=> a[parm].localeCompare(b[parm]) );
}

getDatas() {
   this.http.get<Data[]>(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(it =>this.datas = it)
}


<tbody *ngFor="let data of datas" style="font-size: 12px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve ascending and descending sort using as below

```
sortTable(param){
 this.filteredData.sort((a, b)=> {
   return -1; 
 });
}
```